# wedriverio jenkins - npm command not found error

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, npm-install, webdriver-io

I am trying to run webdriverio test from jenkins and following [this](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/jenkins.html) . I installed `nodeJS` plugin for jenkins and under global tool config, for NodeJS , added a name and installation directory as `/usr/local/bin` (node executable is in this folder)

In Jenkins, in project config , under build environment, I have checked

`Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH` and chosen the node installation name from previous step

But when I am trying to run `npm install
npm test` ,by adding these commands under execute shell under Build and building it,  I receive this error

```
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/wdio-project
[wdio-project] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson1478028169114509075.sh
+ npm install
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson1478028169114509075.sh: line 2: npm: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case someone is looking for same issue, I resolved the above error by adding `export PATH=/usr/local/bin` to the execute shell under build. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179557/jenkins-build-step-fails-when-calling-npm-on-mac-os-x-yosemite) post helped me

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a bug opened about this ([JENKINS-26583](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26583) and [JENKINS-27170](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27170))

I could workaround this bug by adding explicitly node on the PATH by adding this line :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/jenkins/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node_js/bin/
```

Comment: Just a note here that Jenkins home location and the node_js folder may vary depending on your local configuration. "node_js" folder carries the name configured in the Jenkins Global tool configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had just fixed the same issue as you did. 
I wonder if my fix would also help you. When I was using the alpine-based docker image, the Jenkins can never find the npm, but when I use the debian-based docker image, problem solved immediately.

Comment: Did  you do everything you said  on mac os? if yes can you please share, how did you install debian based image on mac?

Comment: @user1207289 hi my host machine is a vps with centos 7.0 x64

Comment: @user1207289 it might be the problem of permission and installation problem

Comment: thanks for commenting. ok, so, then yours was a linux. I am suspecting its not because of debian/alpine. though not fully sure. Was your way of `node.js` installation same as I described above? can you share if you did something else. I want to see if anything is missing in configuring `node.js` or in using this installation under `build environment` tab.

Comment: @user1207289 exactly the same, you could check if the environment path with the command "echo $PATH" and check if the node and npm is under the path directory or not. my problem with alpine is that the path is right and I could find the npm and node uder that directory, but couldnot find them with the command"where is npm"

Comment: when i did `which npm` it gave me `/usr/local/bin/npm` and I checked `/usr/local/bin` is in the `PATH` . I am not sure what else to check. `where is npm` gives me `command not found`

Comment: @user1207289 oh, then I dont know how to deal with that

Answer (score 0):

Try this export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

After installation of NodeJS restart pc

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked -

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`